# Converting Hex to binary in quads

Tags: c, string, printf

This function receives a string representing a HEX Number (e.g. "12a").
Shall return the same value as a dual number in string format, by packages (4 Bit each), e.g.
0001 0010 1010:

```
char* sixteen_to_two(char* hex)
{
char* r_stt = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5 * strlen(hex));
char* begin = r_stt;
do
{
    switch(*hex)
    {
        case '0':
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        break;

        case '1':
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        break;

        case '2':
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        break;

        case '3':
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        break;

        case '4':
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        break;

        case '5':
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        break;

        case '6':
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        break;

        case '7':
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        break;

        case '8':
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = ' ';
        break;

        case '9':
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '1';

        break;

        case 'a':
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        break;

        case 'b':
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        break;

        case 'c':
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        break;

        case 'd':
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        break;

        case 'e':
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '0';
        break;

        case 'f':
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        *r_stt++ = '1';
        break;
    }
    *r_stt++ = ' ';
    hex++;
}
while(*hex != '\0');
return begin;
```

}

Later on, another function wants to scan a Decimal Number and console out the value to the user in various number formats, by doing:

```
printf("= %d(8) = %d(10) = %s(16) = %s(2) \n", dec_to_eight(decimal),  decimal, dec_to_sixteen(decimal), sixteen_to_two(dec_to_sixteen(decimal)));
```

Everything seems to work fine, but, however not for Inputs generating exactly 4 Digits of HEX. Look what happens:

[Look what happens in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPlxS.jpg)

I have no clue where this 0 0 1 9 thing comes from, how to ged rid of it? Thank you so much. If it matters: This is GNOME Terminal 3.0.1

Comment: You need to NULL terminate your string.  ie.: `*r_stt='\0'` or use calloc instead of malloc.

Comment: Tried both options, single and both together. [0 0 1 9] still alive.

Answer (score 2):

Your string is not null terminated. Add the `\0` to the end of the string.

```
char* r_stt = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5 * strlen(hex) + 1);

// Other code

do
{
    // Loop code
} while(*hex != '\0');
*(--r_stt) = '\0'; // <-- Add this line.
return begin;
```

Comment: Actually it needs to be *(--r_stt) = '\0'; // <-- Add this, replace the last space by /0`

Comment: That did the job!

Answer (score 1):

Just as an improvement I would copy the binary representations from an array with [`strcpy`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy). This ensures that the result will be always null-terminated if the destination is large enough to receive the copy:

```
char* sixteen_to_two(char* hex) {
    const char* binary[] = {
        "0000 ", "0001 ", "0010 ", "0011 ",
        "0100 ", "0101 ", "0110 ", "0111 ",
        "1000 ", "1001 ", "1010 ", "1011 ",
        "1100 ", "1101 ", "1110 ", "1111 "
    };

    char* r_stt = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5 * strlen(hex) + 1);
    char* begin = r_stt;

    while(*hex != '\0') {
        int bin_index;

        /* create index from current hexadecimal character */
        if(*hex >= '0' && *hex <= '9')
            bin_index = *hex - '0';
        else if(*hex >= 'A' && *hex <= 'F')
            bin_index = (*hex - 'A') + 10;
        else if(*hex >= 'a' && *hex <= 'f')
            bin_index = (*hex - 'a') + 10;
        else
            break;

        /* copy the binary representation and adjust pointers */
        strcpy(r_stt, binary[bin_index]);
        r_stt += 5;
        hex++;
    }

    return begin;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that when the allocated memory (`malloc`) is not needed anymore, you must return it to the operating system by calling the function `free`.